# q - filter by group frequencies

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I would like to filter a table by a condition on the frequency of groups in a certain column. Example:

Given table

```
tmp:([] id:`a`a`b`b`b`c; c2:1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

first find the frequencies of each group

```
ce:count each group tmp[`id]
```

then select the rows in `tmp` where the `id`'s group count is more than `1`

```
select from tmp where id in where ce > 1

id  c2
a   1
a   2
b   3
b   4
b   5
(row id=`c is gone because it appeared only once)
```

How can this be done more elegant?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fby](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#fby) e.g.

```
q)select from tmp where 1<(count;i) fby id
id c2
-----
a  1
a  2
b  3
b  4
b  5
```

Comment: it's neat to use `i`. it's also possible to use `select from tmp where 1<(count;id) fby id`

Comment: Yep, you can use any column as they'll all be the same length, of course. Conventionally most people will use `i` when doing a count, but any will work.